# Java-WS RS resources structure

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, ejb

For example we have some java-ws rs structure with sub-resources:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/rootpath/")
class Root {

  @Path("/A")
  public A getA {
  ...
  }

  @Path("/B")
  public B getB {
  ...
  }
}

@Stateless  
@LocalBean  
class A {

  @GET
  @Path("/getAStuff")
  public String getAStuff(
      @QueryParam("p") callback: String) {
    return "A stuff";
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/getAnotherAStuff")
  public String getOtherStuff(
      @QueryParam("p") callback: String) {
    return "A stuff";
  }

}

@Stateless 
@LocalBean  
class B {

  @GET
  @Path("/getBStuff")
  public String getBStuff(
      @QueryParam("p") callback: String) {
    return "B stuff";
  } 

}
```

This structure is much more complex in real (wider and deeper). The question is - What is the best way of getA & getB implementation?

I can do this:

```
public A getA {
    return new A();
}
```

Or I can use EJB:

```
@EJB
A a;

public A getA {
    return a;
}
```

Or that way:

```
@Context
private ResourceContext resourceContext;

public A getA {
    A a = resourceContext.getResource(A.class);
    return a;
}
```

The first way give me possibility to read p param in Root class then pass it to A and B through constructor argument without using it in every method of A and B. But Java EE tutorial says that I should use Stateless EJB for webservice classes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, never construct the EJBs yourself - you have a container at hand which is responsible of the lifecycle of your components.

Second, since I assume you use at least Java EE 6, use the common `@Inject` for components.

Third, you don't have to use EJBs, it can as well be a CDI components or plain POJOs.

Finally, I don't understand, why you have a getter for classes `A` and `B` in `Root`? The `@Path` annotation can as well be on your class declaration itself.